# In C++, I need to create a program that loops and stops when a certain number is entered, Then displays the max and min

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

*edit: Fixed the code after realizing I was being a dumbass

Fixed code that works:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int one, two, three = 0, highnum, lownum;
cout << "Enter your first integer: ";
cin >> one;
cout << "\nEnter your second integer: ";
cin >> two;
if (one > two)
{
    highnum = one;
    lownum = two;
}

while (one != -99 && two != -99 && three != -99)
{
    cout << "\nEnter integers until you want to stop (-99 to stop): ";
    cin >> three;
        if (three > one && three > two || three < one && three < two )
        { 
            if (three > one && three > two && three > lownum)
            {
                highnum = three;
            }
            else if ( three < one && three < two && three < lownum)
            {
                lownum = three;
            }
        }
        else if (one > three && one > two || one < three && one < two)
        {
            if (one > three && one > two)
            {
                highnum = one;
            }
            else if (one < three && one < two)
            {
                lownum = one;
            }
        }
        else if ( two > three && two > one || two < one && two < three)
        {
            if ( two > three && two > one)
            {
                highnum = two;
            }
            else if (two < one && two < three)
            {
                lownum = two;
            }
        }
}

cout << "Your lowest number is: "<< lownum << endl << "Your highest number is: " << highnum << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if arrays are the way to go for this type of problem, as we have yet to learn them in our lecture, but I am having some trouble finding the logic behind this looping structure and how to store an infinite number of variables until -99 is entered. Any help is appreciated

The assignment text:
Write a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of integers. The user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest numbers entered.

So far I have taken two different approaches using different combinations of while and for loops, but so far, no dice. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here are the two different versions of the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

/*
int one, two, three=0;
cout << "Enter your first integer: ";
cin >> one;
cout << "Enter you second integer: ";
cin >> two;

while ( one != -99 && two != -99 && three != -99 )
{
  cout << "Enter another integer. To stop the program enter -99: ";
  cin >> three;
}
if  (one < two && three)
  cout << one << endl;
else if (two < one && three)
  cout << two << endl;
else if (three < one && two)
  cout << three << endl;

return 0;
*/
```

And here is my second attempt:

```
int number, number2, number3, counter = 1;
double mul = 1;

cout << "Enter your first number that is not -99";
cin >> number;

while (number !=-99)
{
    cout << "Please enter your second number " <<endl<<endl;
    cin >> number2;
}

for (number != -99; number != -99; counter ++)
{
    cout <<"Please enter another number. ";
    cin >> number3;
}

if (number < number2 && number3)
{
    cout << "The low number is " << number << endl;
    if (number2 < number3)
    cout << "The high number is " << number3 << endl;
}
else if (number2 < number && number3)
{
    cout<< "The low number is " << number2 << endl;
    if (number < number3)
    cout << "The high number is " << number3 << endl;
}
else if (number3 < number && number2)
{
    cout << "The low numer is " << number3 << endl;
    if (number < number2)
    cout << "The high number is " << number2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Don't use three variables for input, use only 1 and then use an array.

Comment: You have posted saying that you're having trouble. Follow through for us: where are you having trouble?

Comment: Right now its just understanding the logic behind the looping process, and storing infinite variables without using an array. I might have figured it out though, one sec...

Comment: You don't really need to store an infinite number of values.  You just need a variable for the current value and one for the min and one for the max.  If the variable for the min were initialized with MAX_INT and the variable for the max were initialized with MIN_INT then it should be easy to keep them up to date during the loop by comparing the current value with them.

Answer (score 3):

Your code and your question title is a little bit controversy.

Based on what I understand about your question, you enter a series of numbers, and when -99 is entered the program will output min, max; but your code is keep entering 2 numbers, compare them and produce output until -99 is entered.

Here is just my raw code, it's not tested yet.

```
int main() {
    int max, min, number;

    cout << "Enter your number (not -99): ";
    cin >> number;
    max = number;
    min = number;

    while(1) {
        cout << "Enter your number (-99 to stop): ";
        cin >> number;
        if (number == -99) { break; }
        if (max < number) { max = number; }
        if (min > number) {min = number; }
    }
    cout << "max: " << max << endl;
    cout << "min: " << min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work granted a user doesn't enter numbers greater than or less than 1000000.

```
int max,min,input;

max = -1000000;
min = 1000000;

cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> input;

while(input!=-99){
    if(input<min) min = input;
    if(input>max) max = input;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> input;
}

cout << "Max: " << max << endl;
cout << "Min: " << min << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

/*I encountered this question tonight and came up with this solution*/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
int inputNum, lownum, highnum;

cout << "Enter as many numbers as you'd like and then I'll show you which\n";
cout << "was highest and which was lowest.\n";
cout << "Enter -99 to end program.\n\n=>";
cin >> inputNum;

//If user enters -99 right away
if (inputNum == -99)
{
    cout << "Ok, we'll thanks for playing anyway\n";
    cin.ignore(); //This & next line pause program after ending.
    cin.get(); 
    return 0;
}

//assign first input number to both high & low values
highnum = inputNum;
lownum = inputNum;


while (inputNum != -99)
{
    cout << "Input number\n=>";
    cin >> inputNum;

    if (inputNum == -99)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (inputNum > highnum)
        highnum = inputNum;

    if (inputNum < lownum)
        lownum = inputNum;
}

cout << "Low number was " << lownum << endl;
cout << "High number was " << highnum << endl;

cin.ignore(); //This & next line pause program after ending.
cin.get();
return 0;

}
```